# Can you connect to a database with just HTTP?

Tags: sql, http

Awhile ago I was looking around for SQL connectivity with my embedded devices and people recommended not to use ODBC because it would not be able to maintain a constant connection if it were wifi etc. So they recommended I just connect using HTTP requests for data-entries etc. So is this possible and if so what do the requests typically look like?

Btw I would use SSL/TLS for encrypted connection because plaintext over the internet is a nono.

Also this would help because all I have learned was microsoft's ODBC library and I relied on it a lot because now I don't know how to connect to MySQL database from Linux as I have not seen a C++ odbc library, so learning the HTTP way would make it more universal.

Comment: I have never seen this being done, but more importantly, what would be the benefit of allowing this assuming your users are already connected to your web application?

Comment: It is depending on the DB you choose. I know some NoSQL databases open their documents as web services, so you can get/update data by sending HTTP requests to these services.